# Criar arquivo XML

Tags: c#, xml

Estou tentando criar um XML mas está ocasionando o seguinte erro:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There was an error generating the XML document.

### Código:

```
 public Boolean GerarArquivoExportacaoOff(String caminhoArquivo)
        {
            Encoding iso_8859_1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(caminhoArquivo, true, iso_8859_1, 100000);

            List<OFFLINE_TABELAS> offline_TabelasList = getListaTabelasAlteradas(); // Seleciona tabelas alteradas

            foreach (OFFLINE_TABELAS Entity_tabelas in offline_TabelasList)
            {
                var lista = getDados(Entity_tabelas.TABELA); // Obtem entidade a partir do nome da tabela


                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(lista.GetType());

                using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("D:/usuarios.xml"))
                {
                    //Definir o Type e o elemento raiz do XML (usuarios)
                    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(lista.GetType(), new XmlRootAttribute("usuarios"));

                    //Serializar o list para o TextWriter e salvar os dados no XML
                    ser.Serialize(textWriter, lista);
                }
}
return true
}
```

O que há de errado nisso ?

Comment: Sem saber onde ocorre o erro fica difícil ajudar. Aproveito para dizer que espero que este método não esteja pronto. Um método que sempre retorna `true` não faz sentido.

Comment: o erro da nessa parte: ser.Serialize(textWriter, lista);

Comment: Coloque o *stack trace* , acho que ficará mais fácil entender.

Comment: Pode colocar o XML na sua pergunta, ou em algum lugar para download?

Comment: no lugar de var list , passei a entidade e deu certo, porem eu preciso que faça dinamicamente de todas as entidades e nao especificamente de uma. ex: List<ED_SERIES> lista = listaEdSeries(); desse jeito funcionou